# seperate mysql server and apache webserver with docker?

Tags: php, mysql, docker, apache2

I have my apache2 webserver in one docker container. Users can type an email and it will store it in a SQL database. But when i try and run a different docker container specifically for the mysql server, the connection is refused.

Docker container for webserver: docker run -t -d -p 80:80 --name webserver ubuntu

Docker container for mysql server: docker run -t -d -p 3306:3306 --name mysql_server ubuntu

heres my php code to store the data:

```
<?php

$servername = "1.1.1.1:3306"; //yes i know i need to put a valid IP here. Just put this as an example
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "Emails";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$email = $_POST['email'];

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "invalid email format";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (email)
VALUES ('$email')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
  header("Location: Thankyou.html");
  exit;
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Does 1.1.1.1 represent the address of the host machine, or a docker container?

Comment: Can you provide your images' Dockerfiles?  You couldn't run this script in a plain `ubuntu` container.  You might consider using Docker Compose to launch the two containers, and [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes the network environment there; that page is useful reading even if you're manually using `docker network create` to create the container network.

Answer (score 0):

If i got it correctly, you have a container running mysql and a container running apache.
The error might indicate mysql is not configured to accept connections from the subnet where apache is running.
Make sure apache dockers can successfully connect and authenticate to mysql.